# Unregister remote notification on logout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, push-notification

About **`unregisterForRemoteNotifications`**

From the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications)

> You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a new version of the app removes support for all types of remote notifications. Users can temporarily prevent apps from receiving remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings app. Apps unregistered through this method can always re-register.

Some are saying:

> Calling it would at times put the app in a state where calling
>   registerForRemoteNotifications would no longer work.

Why did `apple` tell us to use it in **rare circumstances only** and gave such an extreme example of if new version of app removes push notification support completely. Isn't it fit for the logout button action?

In our app users can login with multiple devices. It would be lot easier if `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` works well. Anybody using `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` on logout button?

Comment: Would this not potentially mean they could be prompted every time they log in to accept the push notification permissions? That would be annoying... I've done this before by setting a loggedIn flag on my server, and the server determines if it should send pushes to the device or if the user is logged in...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, You can use `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` on Logout.

This function is used to unregister all the notification from Apple Store.

You always can re register to notification with `registerForRemoteNotifications` and start receiving the push notification. And that you may need to do it in your success Login.

If you read that sentence from Apple Doc carefully than its last line clearly says that `Apps unregistered through this method can always re-register.`

They are suggesting developers if they dont want to receive push notification for some time than they can just simply disable from the settings. But for login and logout session you are doing right with by calling  `unregisterForRemoteNotifications`

And New version will stop receiving notification means after your logout you will never receive any notification till you re register for it.

Comment: I my experience on iOS 10 after `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` is called, even if I call `registerForRemoteNotifications` again I will not receive a token from Apple until the app is deleted and reinstalled.

Comment: I have just been testing this on iOS 9 (iPad 2) and have found that after unregistering, the app needs to be completely killed and reopened before any push notifications are received. Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: rdar://28875922 addresses this issue

Comment: Does anybody know if this is still an issue on iOS 13?